# char * versus unsigned char * and casting

Tags: c, sqlite, character-encoding

I need to use the SQLite function `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` (https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html).

This function takes a `const char *` as its second parameter.

On the other hand, I have prepared an `unsigned char *` variable `v` which contains something like this:

```
INSERT INTO t (c) VALUES ('amitié')
```

In hexadecimal representation (I cut the line):

```
49 4E 53 45 52 54 20 49 4E 54 4F 20 74 20 28 63 29
20 56 41 4C 55 45 53 20 28 27 61 6D 69 74 69 E9 27 29
```

Note the `0xE9` representing the character `é`.

In order for this piece of code to be built properly, I cast the variable `v` with `(const char *)` when I pass it, as an argument, to the sqlite3_prepare_v2() function...

What comments can you make about this cast? Is it really very very bad?

Note that I have been using an `unsigned char *` pointer to be able to store characters between `0x00` and `0xFF` with one byte only.

The source data is coming from an ANSI encoded file.

In the documentation for the `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` function, I'm also reading the following comment for the second argument of this function:

```
/* SQL statement, UTF-8 encoded */
```

What troubles me is the type `const char *` for the function second argument... I would have been expecting a `const unsigned char *` instead...

To me - but then again I might be totally wrong - there are only 7 useful bits in a char (one byte), the most significant bit (leftmost) being used to denote the sign of the byte...

I guess I'm missing some kind of point here...

Thank you for helping.

Comment: When dealing with multi-byte characters, the data type `char` simply means one byte. `unsigned` is not necessary.

Comment: For some compilers, the default representation of unadorned `char` is actually `signed char`. It's one of those few areas where the original committee punted the decision over to the compiler implementors - and it causes a lot of problems with portability between compilers.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

For a UTF-8 input, the `sqlite3_prepare_v2` method really should be asking for a `const unsigned char *` as all 8 bits are being used for data. Their implementation certainly shouldn't be using a signed comparison to check the top bit, because a simple compiler flag can set the default for `char` to be either `unsigned` or `signed` and the former would break the code.

As for your concerns over the cast, this is one of the more benign ones. Casting away signedness on `int` or `float` is usually a *very bad thing* (TM) - or at least a clear indicator that you have a problem.

When dealing with pure ASCII, you are correct that there are 7-bits of data, but the remaining 8th bit is meant to be used for a parity bit, not as a sign bit.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Shall I use the type "char *" for the variable "v" then (instead of casting)?

Comment: Personally, I always use an explicit `unsigned char *` for character data, `signed char *` for numeric (i.e.byte−sized) data, and cast when required by a foreign API. I try to avoid an unadorned `char *`.

Comment: I came here because I have similar question. Raw bytes are represented as `unsigned char buf*`. Yet, the **C++** `std::ifstream::read` method expects a `char*`. So, I ended up sprinkling lots of casting to build the code. Is it safe to represent raw bytes as `char*` such that no more need to cast when using these **C++** stuff?